# How to use angularJS trustAsHtml only for one HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to highlight only one specific HTML tag  (from elasticsearch) and escape all the rest.

I'm using angular 1.5.5

the filter I use  :

```
angular.module('filters', [])
.filter('unsafe',['$sce', function ($sce) {
        return function (content) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
        };
    }])
```

in html :

```
<p class="small" ng-bind-html="file.content | characters:460 | unsafe"></p>
```

and if the content is something like that :

```
Java class for <mark>RoleStatusCancelled</mark>.
```

it's ok, and i have a good result
but if i had :

```
<a href="../Outils.<mark>html</mark>#extensionJPG"><b>extensionJPG</b></a>
```

it gives me an [interpreted html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpyDU.png)
but i expect something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96cUE.png)

I search for a long time a solution but still in trouble :(

Comment: Hello Pankaj, yes it's well included, my problem is how getting only one HTML tag and escape the rest :)

Comment: @Jérémie how you know wich tag you want to highlight and wich one escape?

Comment: i know that the only tag i want is <mark> (it's generated from elasticsearch).

Comment: The workaround i found is to replace all `<` and `>` by `&lt;` and `&gt;`
Then I replace 
`&lt;mark&gt; by <mark>`
and 
`&lt;/mark&gt; by </mark>`
But it's not really beautiful :-/